# How to show a bootstrap tooltip messege using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to show a tooltip messege when we want to give a messege for a input box like textbox like email already exists etc using bootstrap.

```
function signup()
{
  if($('#name').val().length==0)
  {
    //show tooltip messege that this box is empty
  }
}


<div class="form-group">

    <label for="name">Name of the Company/Individual:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">

</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="signup()">Submit</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Read How to Ask Question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your code needs formatting.

Comment: ya i got it sir...and thanku

Comment: I am totally agree with @Jhon, you must know how to ask question. Also It is expected that you have read atleast documentation of bootstrap before ask question.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-methods

Comment: here is what you need, modify it to suit your need http://www.tutorialspark.com/twitterBootstrap/TwitterBootstrap_Tooltip_Javascript_Method_destroy.php

Comment: For validation you can [check this out](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html)

Comment: saquieb,, i want the messege just below the textbox and it should be positioned not anywhere..

Comment: @Uzzwal I will suggest you to use a library [like this](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) to achieve what you want

Comment: i dont want to validate using bootstrap style,i just want to validate in my style and show the toltip messege thats why i cant use library

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group margin-bottom-20">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="radio" name="userType" id="ind" value="INDIVIDUAL"><span class="test" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Individual tooltip message." data-placement="right" > Individual</span>
<input type="radio" name="userType" id="corp" value="CORPORATION"><span class="test" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Corporation tooltip message." data-placement="left" > Corporation </span

</div>
</div>
```

> Use bootstrap css

Comment: hey i want to do it by javascript or jquery beacuse i want different different messege based on validation like one time it is empty and another data is not valid.